# easyui treegrid "load" method

Tags: jquery-easyui

Hello i want to ask about load method for easyui treegrid
I read easyui treegrid documentation from this URL http://jeasyui.com/documentation/treegrid.php
I didn't found treegrid load method, but since i know treegrid dependencies from datagrid, so i go to this URL http://jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php
In easyui datagrid, load method code format, look like this
*`$('#dg').datagrid('load',{code: '01',name: 'name01'});`*
Let me explain a little about code above, the code above load datagrid with some condition, code='01' and name='name01', from datagrid URL. Code and name treated as HTTP_POST_VAR in datagrid URL php file, further use for SQL condition value
But, when I try to implement datagrid load method in my treegrid, look like this below code
*`$('#dg').treegrid('load',{code: '01',name: 'name01'});`*
It can't send HTTP_POST_VAR
Is it true, that easyui treegrid don't have load method like datagrid? Is there any other solution to load easyui treegrid with some condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically load the treegrid data using 'loadData' like below,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async : false,
    url:'someURL.action?code=01&name=name01',       
    success: function(obj) {
        $('#treegridId').treegrid('loadData', obj);
     }
});
```

or simply by

```
$('#treegridId').treegrid({  
    url:'someURL.action?code=01&name=name01'});
```